# Get duration of the current song in AppleScript

Tags: applescript, itunes, duration

I'm trying to make a script to get the duration of the current song, but when I do this the duration comes back as "missing value". Any suggestions?

```
tell application "iTunes"
    if player state is playing or player state is paused then
        set theDuration to (get duration of the current track)
        display dialog theDuration
    end if
end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works perfectly here. For example, I play "How Many Times" from Bob Marley and when I run your script the dialog shows `145.1920013427734`. But (of course) when I play Internet Radio, `duration` will return nothing. Try a local track and run your script again ? Just guessing. (iTunes 11.0.5 / OS X 10.8.2)

Comment: Yep. That answers my question. I was listening to iTunes Radio when I made this so that explains it. Thanks